# MySQL joining the previous occurrence of a record

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the query that lists that dates that a store was open and closed. What I want is the previous open date so for example for 2014-12-27 it would be 2014-12-26. The store wasn't open on New Years so for 2015-01-02 it would be 2014-12-31.

Every time I sit down to write the query I get nowhere, I have tried subselects, case statements, joining subqueries, subqueries in the where clause and I still can't figure this one out. Any help on this would be much appreciated?

EDIT
Clarifying that the column date_nk is an integer, and add the column "previous_date" to show the desired output.

```
    date_nk         weekday     opened     previous_open_date
1.  20141226        Friday      1          20141225
2.  20141227        Saturday    0          20141226
3.  20141228        Sunday      0          20141226
4.  20141229        Monday      1          20141226 
5.  20141230        Tuesday     1          20141229
6.  20141231        Wednesday   1          20141230
7.  20150101        Thursday    0          20141231 
8.  20150102        Friday      1          20141231
9.  20150103        Saturday    0          20150102 
10. 20150104        Sunday      0          20150102
```

Comment: show what query you tried please?

Comment: Please show us your desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the column previous_date to show the desired outcome

Comment: I'm not convinced that either of the answers below solve your problem.

Comment: I wrote a python script to loop through every date and uses the accepted answers query to update the rows previous_open_date

Comment: OK but this isn't really the way to go.  You can do it with a single query, thereby avoiding all that network usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below.

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cec34/1/0)

```
SELECT 
 date_nk, 
 weekday,
 opened,
 (select max(date_nk) from OpenTable PO
  where PO.date_nk < CU.date_nk and
       PO.Opened = 1) PrevDate
  from OpenTable CU
  order by date_nk;
```

Comment: This almost works and will likely be the one I accept, but for dates like 20141227 I would want to see 20141226

Comment: I edited the original question and added an desired output column to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I think this is what the OP is really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look difficult if I understod you.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE opened = '1' AND date_nk < 'yourdate' LIMIT 1;
```

I don't knwo the type of your `date_nk` field, you should think about use date types but I think that should work.

Comment: Is there anyway to scale that to an entire table in a single query? If not I might just write a script in python that iterates over every record and does this and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I didn't understand you now, you asked the previous date, the first one I guessed that's why I used `LIMIT 1`